# Advice for building a home automation system

Tags: smart-home, mqtt

I am not sure what technologies to use in order to build an IoT system for my home.

I have a few sensors and some other devices that need to be controlled (like a doorlock) placed in my house. All of them have WiFi integrated. I want to see all the sensors data and be able to control my devices from my phone.

My idea was to connect all my devices to a local network and run a MQTT broker locally. Then I would build an application that connects to that broker, so it could be able to receive any messages the sensors and devices send and also publish a message on a specific topic, so a device can change a state (for example unlocking the door). I'm thinking that this application should be a webserver api because it would be easy to communicate with a mobile application.

Here's a simple representation of what I described:

[image]

Now, I'm not sure if this is a good approach. Are there any better methods? I would like to keep things locally, so an online service that does this for me wouldn't really help.

Comment: Hi, Welcome to IoT Stack Exchange. As a rule questions like this ("is this good" and "what is better") tend to lead to opinion based answers which do not fit with the Question/Answer structure of Stack Exchange (where questions should be able to have definative correct answer. It is also probably a bit too broad. https://iot.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: since you have the hardware, perhaps you could use an online broker to run a quick test to see if it can be done in the way that you are thinking ... here us one that gives you visual feedback https://shiftr.io/

Comment: Although the phrasing of the question suggests 'opinion based', I suspect this is _the_ default architecture. Maybe the two protocols can vary? I'd suggest maybe asking 'is this a common architecture', or 'will this work as I assume'.